# MinDate and MaxDate are not working for the native date picker in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 project and I have used the native date picker plugin. It is working fine but I am not able to set the min and max date in it for the Android.

This is my **tab2.page.html**:

```
<ion-input formControlName="startchallenge" placeholder="Select Date" (click)="datePickershow()" [readonly]=true></ion-input>
```

This is my **tab2.page.ts**:

```
datePickershow(){
this.datePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK,
      minDate: new Date().toISOString(),
      maxDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 10)).toISOString(),
    }).then(
      date => console.log('Got date: ', date)},
      err => {
        console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)}
    );
  }
```

I have used min and max date in Android after that the user is able to select the back date from today because I have used the min date as a today date but the problem is that user is able to select the previous date in Android.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
minDate: new Date().valueOf(),
maxDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 10)).valueOf(),
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime), which provide easiest way to getting date or time from user.
There are lots of methods to formate date and time input.

Comment: I was using that but my client doesn't like the UI so I changed to this.

Comment: In this, Can you please help me?

Comment: Sorry @Raghav, I have no idea how to change the UI.

Comment: Okay. but Can you help me in this question?

Comment: Which type of help you need ? I will sure help you, if i am able to.

Comment: With the answer of this question?

Comment: Yes, But I have no idea how to develop custom UI for ionic date picker.

Comment: Ok. I just found that you are setting date type value in min and max but as the document suggestion you should to use string value in min and max. So convert that min and max value to string.

Comment: I have updated my question and after that It is not working.

Comment: Okay. No problem. Thanks.